# How rotate a Data Frame bar plot in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I found this plot and i would like to rotate it. My goal is to have the bars in the vertical axis. **SIMILAR to the 2nd one plot.**

```
plot = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['LIFESTAGE', 'PREMIUM_CUSTOMER']).TOT_SALES.sum()) 

plot.unstack().plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True, figsize = (12, 7), title = 'Total Sales by Customer Segment')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe `kind='barh'`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `kind = 'barh'`

Please refer to : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

[image: sklearn documentation snapshot]